# Delete from a hash linear probe

Tags: java, hashtable

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code but it fails at deletion of PS in the following [null, null, null, PS]

```
 /**
 * Removes the specified string from this hash table     
 * (if the string is in this table).    
 */
public void delete(String s) {
    // TODO
    int k = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<M;i++) {
        if (keys[i] != null) {
            if (keys[i] == s) {

                k = i;
        }
        }
    }
    keys[k] = null;
    for (int i=k;i<M;i++) {
        if (keys[i+1]!=null) {
            keys[i] = keys[i+1];
        }
    }
    N--;


    // halves size of array if it's 12.5% full or less
    if (N > 0 && N <= M/8) resize(M/2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what the error is but looking at the code I see these problems:

1. Comparison between `String` should be performed using `equals` and not `==` otherwise you are not comparing the values of the strings but their references
2. if `keys` size is `M` then `keys[i+1]` will cause an out of bounds exception in the last cycle of the second `for` loop